# Postback in Block UI using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, blockui

I use a blockui jquery in my webpage. 
The issue is its not taking the settimeout function when it is postback. 
It just blocks only for few seconds. 
I tried from the d site.
http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page 
and tried many alternative ways like ajaxStart and ajaxstop events too. 
 It doesn't take the time when the page is postback.My code as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#demo10').click(function () {
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<h1>Auto-Unblock!</h1>'
                });
                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 8000); 
            });
        }); </script>

    <div>
    <asp:Button ID="demo10" runat="server" Text="Run" />
    </div>
```

Comment: You are doing ajaxPostBack or normal post back?

Comment: You sure setTimeOut is called on intial load ?

Comment: Instead of button , if i use a label , its working fine .

Comment: I have tried your script, its working fine on even post back also. Are you sure about the problem ? by the way check for any errors in the console/error log

Comment: yes . did u checked for the settimeout function. ?

Comment: Yes, setTimeout is triggering and it is unblocking also.

Comment: Unblocking is working fine but its not taking the time 8000 seconds and for other values . Did you checked for multiple values ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably because you let the click make post back. Return false on the click event to prevent it as:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#demo10').click(function () {
                $.blockUI({
                    message: '<h1>Auto-Unblock!</h1>'
                });
                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 8000); 

                return false;
            });
        });
```

In the page with the examples the button is not input control, and not product post back, thats why on the sample code did not use this `return false;` In your case your button rendered as input control, and this make post back.